# If $|G| = p^nq$ then $G$ has only one normal subgroup of order $q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I was trying to solve a problem on Sylow-p subgroups that read

> If $G$ is such that $|G| = p^nq$ with $p>q$ primes, show that $G$ has only one normal subgroup of index $q$.

Answering this requires only one of the Sylow theorems and is quite easy to prove. I was distracted, however, and was trying to prove

> If $G$ is such that $|G| = p^nq$ with $p>q$ primes, show that $G$ has only one normal subgroup of **order** $q$.

I tried several things, mainly pointing towards trying to prove that said normal subgroup was the Sylow-q subgroup of $G$. I tried assuming $H, K$ were normal subgroups of $G$ with order $q$ and tried to show $H = K$; I tried induction on the exponent $n$ in $|G| = p^nq$; I tried taking the quotient $G/P$ where $P$ is the only Sylow-p subgroup...

I didn't make any of that work, but I also failed to provide a counter-example, hence I am looking for hints in the right direction.

Comment: Try $S_3$ for a counter example.

Comment: Your title talks about subgroups of order $q$, the question body about subgroups of index $q$. Which is it? Hint: the answer depends... See Tobias' comment.

Comment: Maybe the body of the question is confusing, but what I try to tell is that the original question in my textbook read **index**, which I proved swiftly. However, before noticing the textbook read **index**, I was trying to prove the exact same statement but with the word index replaced by **order**. My question here regards the altered statement with subgroups of **order** $q$. Tobias's comment makes me believe the statement is thus false.

Comment: Oops. Sorry, I didn't read it all, and jumped to a conclusion. Indeed, that other statement is false in general if $p^t\equiv1\pmod q$ for some $t, 0<t\le n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments point out, a counter-example arises easily by considering $S_3$.

Indeed, $|S_3| = 3\cdot2$ so we make $p=3,q=2$. Now we show that there are $3$ Sylow-2 subgroups of order $2$, namely

$$\langle(1\ 2)\rangle, \langle(1\ 3)\rangle, \langle(2\ 3)\rangle$$

which are as many as there could be, for if $n$ is the number of Sylow-2 subgroups, we have $n|3 \wedge n \equiv 1\ \mod2$ implying we have the case $n = 3$.